# ¿como habilitar `cors`?

Tags: api, php5, codeigniter-3, axios, cors

Contexto, cree una api restful con codeigniter 3, la cual me permite consumirla desde postman y con ajax de jq en localhost o desde otro dominio de la web. Cuando quiero consumirla desde una aplicación creada en note que utiliza axios me manda el siguiente error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'ruta api' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
const repuesta = await clienteAxios.get("link_api", {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Inl1cmk4OSIsImNhZHVjaWRhZCI6MTU4MjMwMjkxMX0.Aa7cKdNFx0whL2ePgp3eqa32SIw4LWfezdtcxnFdw6I`
                }
            })
```

configuración de codeigniter:

```
$config['check_cors'] = TRUE;

$config['allowed_cors_headers'] = [
  'Origin',
  'X-Requested-With',
  'Content-Type',
  'Accept',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method'
];

$config['allowed_cors_methods'] = [
  'GET',
  'POST',
  'OPTIONS',
  'PUT',
  'PATCH',
  'DELETE'
];


$config['allow_any_cors_domain'] = TRUE;


$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = [];


$config['forced_cors_headers'] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas darle permiso al dominio que va a acceder a tu aplicacion en este caso 'http://localhost:3000'

```
$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = ['http://localhost:3000'];
```